# Network storage application

Tags: linux, networking, file-sharing, cifs

I have android device eGreat U9 with attached external HDD. I'd like to use this device also as a NAS and mount it's drive as a network disk on my linux desktop. Here is what I've already tried:

- SMB/CIFS server - transfer rates low and significant delay when mounted
- SSHFS - even worse than the previous one (probably because of encryption overhead)
- FTP - transfer rate over 8-10MB/s, so problem is not in my network at all, but when I tried to use ftp mount, it was really unusable

Is there any other way I can use it as a network storage? I tried more than one app for every solution above, but if you know about some certain application, that works for you, I would appreciate your advice.

On the device is rooted Android 4.2.

Comment: I can offer you a list of [Various File Servers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server_file), including some for WebDAV (which you didn't try yet it seems). Apart from that, lists of vaious [FTP Servers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server_ftp) and [SSH Clients & Server](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sshclients) I have as well. With *Linux* on the desktop, NFS daemons might be a choice as well (list missing, oops!).

Comment: PS: [Servers Ultimate](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate) is an app including an NFS server. Just updating the "various" listing, so later today there should be more alternatives.

Comment: Neither of them works. I've also tried [Complete linux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid&hl=en) and installed samba on it, but transfer rate is still about 2MB/s.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try webdav with apache, and davfs2 on the client side. This should be about the same speed as FTP.

NFS is also an option, if your kernel supports it. However, if you want some security (neither of these options has encryption (ok, webdav can run over http), but at least authentication), nfs authentication is pretty hard to set up compared to webdav.

If you want some *real* security, you can use SFTP/sshfs, and fiddle with the SFTP's encryption settings, namely the set the Ciphers and MACs options (you have to set these client-side). There is probably a combination that is significantly faster, and any is still much more secure than nothing.

And for any of these, I would use some chroot-ed linux with native code, e.g. debian (it's quite easy to install with Lil'debi).